# Skipping to next value if button is clicked otherwise keep timer alive

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following code:

```
startReplay(replayValues: Object) {
  this.replayRunning = true;
  var firstTs: number;
  const repObs = Observable.from(Object.keys(replayValues)).filter(key => Object.keys(diff(replayValues[key], this.initialFormObject)).length > 0);
  repObs.first().subscribe(key => firstTs = Number(key));

  return repObs
    .delayWhen(key => Observable.timer(Number(key) - firstTs))
    .map(key => replayValues[key])
    .finally(() => this.replayRunning = false)
    .takeWhile(() => this.replayRunning === true);
}
```

I have the `observable` that emits values from an `array`. The `array` has timestamps as `keys` and `objects` as values. I run through this array as an `observable` and subscribe elsewhere (and let's assume print to console).

As you see, the `observable` emits a value after x (= `Number(key) - firstTs`) seconds. Afterwards, I map it and only emit the objects and don't care about the timestamps anymore. I want to run this until the value for `replayRunning` is `true`.

Now, I have a button in my `app.component.html` that calls the currently empty function `skipReplayStep() {}` in my code. Now, I want to have the possibility to stop the `delayWhen()` and immediately go forward to the next step, i.e. `map(key =>...)` is started.

### Initial thoughts (but not practical solution)

I thought about `merge` + `first()` where the `Observable.timer(Number(key) - firstTs)` part is merged with an `EventEmitter`. But I wasn't able to get the `EventEmitter` turned into an `Observable`. Also, I don't think it's the best way, I think. My problem there is also, that I think the `EventEmitter` will cancel every `delayWhen()` when I only want to cancel the nearest `delayWhen()`.

### Edit: Trial at marble diagram

```
1 |----X|
2 |------X|
3 |--------------X|
4 |--------------------X|
5 |--------------------------------X|
6 |-------------------------------------------------X|
7 |-X-----X-------------X---X--->
R |-X----XX------------XX---X|
```

So, the observers `1` through `6` are timers based on the timestamps I described above. `7` is the click event emitter (i.e. when the button is being clicked). `R` is the result. As you hopefully see, the clicks are mapped in order to the respective observable. So the first observer is linked to the first click, etc. This leads to the fact that observers 5 and 6 would not be emitted until the result `Observable` is finished due to two clicks being emitted.

### Edit 2: Slight error in Marble

I think there is a slight error in the marble. It doesn't account for the fact that the time between the "normal" should be kept and thus reduce the overall existence of the `Observable`.

### Edit 3: Plunker added

https://plnkr.co/edit/rV0aDTcSVf4xlnVUJNJN

Here is the Plunker to play around with. Let me know if that makes sense. I trimmed it a bit from the function above (filter is not applicable for the Plunker as it relies on something else, but consider it working).

Comment: @Brandon if this reaches you, you might be my last hope.

Comment: You could have created a plnkr to play around ?

Comment: Good point, will add this and edit. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever wonders how to solve this, maybe this gives him an idea. This solved my problem:

```
startReplay(replayValues: Object) {
  this.replayRunning = true;
  const obsRepValues = Observable
    .from(Object.keys(replayValues))
    .filter(key => Object.keys(diff(replayValues[key], this.initialFormObject)).length > 0)

  const obsTimestamps = obsRepValues.map((x, i) => Number(x));
  const obsValues = obsRepValues.map((x, i) => replayValues[x]);
  const obsIndex = obsRepValues.map((x, i) => i + 1);

  const obsTimeDiff = obsRepValues
    .pairwise()
    .map(key => Math.ceil((Number(key[1]) - Number(key[0])) / 100) * 100)
    .startWith(0);
  const obsTimeElapsed = obsTimeDiff.scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

  const obsResult = Observable.zip(obsIndex, obsTimestamps, obsValues, obsTimeDiff, obsTimeElapsed);
  const obsTimer = obsResult;
  return obsResult
    .delayWhen(x =>
      Observable.race(
        Observable.interval(10).skipWhile(() => x[0] != this.currentReplayStep), //BehaviourSubject + skip(x)
        Observable.interval(10).skipWhile(() => (x[0] - 1) != this.currentReplayStep).delay(x[3]) //BehaviourSubject + skip(x - 1) + delay
      )
    )
    .takeWhile(() => this.replayRunning === true)
    .do(x => {
      this.currentReplayStep = x[0];
      const interval: number = 100;
      obsTimeDiff
        .skipWhile(() => x[0] != this.currentReplayStep)
        .elementAt(x[0], 0)
        .switchMap(duration => Observable.timer(0, interval).mapTo(-interval).scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, duration).map(x => x / 1000))
        .takeWhile(() => this.replayRunning === true && x[0] == this.currentReplayStep)
        .finally(() => this.timerValue = 0)
        .subscribe(y => this.timerValue = y);
    })
    .map(x => x[2])
    .finally(() => this.stopReplay());
}

skipToNext() {
  this.currentReplayStep = this.currentReplayStep + 1;
}
```

I currently work on a solution using a `BehaviorSubject` which would emit instead of `obsResult`. In theory, it's not too difficult. I am missing an operator (or maybe don't know of it) that emits the same position as the "previous" `Observable`. Pseudo code style:

```
BehaviorSubject.race(2 Observables).WantedOperator(emittingNewObservable)
```